# Pandas: check if a value error is in an interval, error message: InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Tags: pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
target_price    interval
0.001767    [0.00318240, 0.00318624]
0.002978    [0.00318576, 0.00319673]
0.000174    [0.00319581, 0.00319617]
0.002740    [0.00318881, 0.00319617]
```

The code is used: 
`for index,interval in df.iterrows():
    if interval.target_price in interval.interval:
        df['check']= True`

But I have the following error message: `InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]`

Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Does the `interval` column contain python lists?

Comment: Do not really understand your question, this is how I created my interval column : `for index,interval in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index,'interval'] = pd.Interval(left= interval.low, right=interval.high, closed='both') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is `list`

```
df['check']=[y[0]<=x<=y[1] for x , y in zip(df.target_price,df.interval)]
Out[43]: [False, False, False, False]
```

If it is interval

```
df['check']=[x in y for x , y in zip(df.target_price,df.interval)]
```

---More info

```
df.interval.apply(type)
Out[52]: 
0    <class 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'>
1    <class 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'>
2    <class 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'>
3    <class 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'>
Name: interval_1, dtype: object
```

Comment: How am I suppose to use that? Thanks!

Comment: For the second one I have the following error: `TypeError: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object does not support indexing`

Comment: @Viktor.w it is ok on my side ,

Comment: @Viktor.w also How about not convert to interval , just do , `df.target_price.between(df.low,df.high)`

Comment: This way you mean: `df['check'] = df.target_price.between(df.low,df.high)`?

Comment: I still have the error `InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]` :(

Comment: `df['check'] = df.target_price.between(df.low,df.high)` it woooo!oorks! Thanks